# Как правильно восстановить решение в задаче о рюкзаке?

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
static int[] pokupki = new int[]{
        204, 259, 130, 151, 210, 89, 260, 124, 331, 159, 305, 223, 49, 89, 299, 318,
        215, 800, 195, 189, 215, 159, 110
};

static int knapsack(int weights[], int costs[], int needed) {
    int n = weights.length;
    int dp[][] = new int[needed + 1][n + 1];
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= needed; w++) {
            if (weights[j - 1] <= w) {
                dp[w][j] = Math.max(dp[w][j - 1], dp[w - weights[j - 1]][j - 1] + costs[j - 1]);
            } else {
                dp[w][j] = dp[w][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    int w = needed;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = weights.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int current = dp[w][i];

        if (dp[w][i - 1] == current) {
            continue;
        } else if (dp[w - weights[i]][i - 1] + weights[i - 1] == current) {
            sum += weights[i - 1];
            w -=  weights[i];
            System.out.println("take " + weights[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total:" + sum);
    return dp[needed][n];
}
```

}

Comment: "ваш" код поразительно похож на [этот](https://pascal-ua.at.ua/news/zadacha_o_rjukzake/2011-12-02-1).

Answer (score 0):

Ну давайте разбираться.
Создаётся таблица, номер строки соответствует весу, столбец  - номеру предмета.
В ячейке [w][k] лежит наилучшая **стоимость** набора из предметов до k-того, с весом не более w. В эту ячейку приходим либо слева, либо слева-сверху, добавляя цену взятого предмета.

А при разматывании решения во втором if сравнивается теплое с мягким - складывается стоимость и вес

```
else if (dp[w - weights[i]][i - 1] + weights[i - 1] == current)
```

а должно быть, видимо

```
else if (dp[w - weights[i]][i - 1] + costs[i - 1] == current)
```

Подозреваю, что это сравнение может вообще быть лишним - раз уж мы пришли не слева - значит, из известной ячейки слева-сверху